# I'm trying to save my result into a new file but got problems - Python

Tags: python, extract, pdb

I'm trying to make an script which takes all rows starting by 'HELIX', 'SHEET' and 'DBREF' from a .txt, from that rows takes some specifical columns and then saves the results on a new file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("2 Parameters expected: You must introduce your pdb file and a name for output file.")`
    exit()

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    if 'HELIX' in line:
        helix = line.split()
        cols_h = helix[0], helix[3:6:2], helix[6:9:2]
    elif 'SHEET'in line:
        sheet = line.split()
        cols_s = sheet[0], sheet[4:7:2], sheet[7:10:2], sheet [12:15:2], sheet[16:19:2]
    elif 'DBREF' in line:
        dbref = line.split()
        cols_id = dbref[0], dbref[3:5], dbref[8:10]


modified_data = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
modified_data.write(cols_id)
modified_data.write(cols_h)
modified_data.write(cols_s)
```

My problem is that when I try to write my final results it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funcional2.py", line 21, in <module>
    modified_data.write(cols_id)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

When I try to convert to a string using ''.join() it returns another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funcional2.py", line 21, in <module>
    modified_data.write(' '.join(cols_id))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Also, if there is some easy way to simplify my code, it'll be great.
PS: I'm no programmer so I'll probably need some explanation if you do something...

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you do `print cols_id` before the `modified_data.write(cols_id)`?

Comment: `write` expects a "character buffer object", e.g. a `str`, but you are giving it a `tuple` - convert this to a string first. See any one of the thousand other questions on SO for ["\[python\] TypeError character buffer object"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+TypeError+character+buffer+object).

Comment: Kobi K, thanks for asking that, I can only print cols_id inside my for loop. Outside only prints the first row. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cols_id, cols_h and cols_s seems to be lists, not strings.
You can only write a string in your file so you have to convert the list to a string.

```
modified_data.write(' '.join(cols_id))
```

and similar.

`'!'.join(a_list_of_things)` converts the list into a string separating each element with an exclamation mark

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
print("2 Parameters expected: You must introduce your pdb file and a name for output     file.")`
exit()

cols_h, cols_s, cols_id = []

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
  if 'HELIX' in line:
    helix = line.split()
    cols_h.append(''.join(helix[0]+helix[3:6:2]+helix[6:9:2]))
  elif 'SHEET'in line:
    sheet = line.split()
    cols_s.append( ''.join(sheet[0]+sheet[4:7:2]+sheet[7:10:2]+sheet[12:15:2]+sheet[16:19:2]))
  elif 'DBREF' in line:
    dbref = line.split()
    cols_id.append(''.join(dbref[0]+dbref[3:5]+dbref[8:10]))

modified_data = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
cols = [cols_id,cols_h,cols_s]
for col in cols:
  modified_data.write(''.join(col))
```

Comment: The same thing to the previous comment, it still doesn't work.
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funcional2.py", line 21, in <module>
    modified_data.write(' '.join(cols_id))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found]

Comment: I just noticed that cols_id is a list of lists, so you have to do the following: `cols_id = ''.join(dbref[0])+''.join(dbref[3:5])+''.join(dbref[8:10])`

Comment: And also... every time your loop takes a new line, you sobstitute the content of your cols_whatever variables, so in the end you'll have only the last found.  If you want all the cols found you have to initialize your variables (`cols_s, cols_h, cols_id = ''`) and do the `cols_whathever += new stuff`

Comment: I've tried to to this: cols = ''
  cols_id = cols + (''.join(dbref[0])+ '-' + '-'.join(dbref[3:5])+ '-' + '-'.join(dbref[8:10])) but when I use print command out of my for loop it still prints only the last row :(

Comment: Didn't understood what you tried :) but I added final code in my answer.  Basically you need to initialize with an empty string your variables, then you need to add (+=) the found data to the existing string.  What you wrote in the comment seems like: "cols is empty, every time you find DBREF cols_id becomes cols (empty) + the foundthing.. so the last time it founds DBREF you put empty + your last result in cols_id

Comment: Now I really don't understand why it still doesn't work. I've used your suggestions but now it returns another kind of error!
"  File "1funcional2.py", line 17
    elif 'DBREF' in line:
       ^
"

Comment: Haha, well, I tried to do what I thought you were suggesting, but as I said, I'm not a programmer XD (in fact I'm biologist). I've tried your final code and now it does another strange thing... and I can't see why.

Comment: @Hrabal There are `+` operators missing to make this syntactically correct and repeatedly concatenating strings in a loop is an „anti pattern” in Python. Strings are immutable so every time you add something the old values are copied into a new string, and the strings grow bigger each iteration, so more and more data has to be copied around. The idiomatic approad would be collecting the strings into a list and use a string `join()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you everybody! I've finally achieved what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (untested) that separates data and code a little more.  There is a data structure (`keyword_and_slices`) describing the keywords searched in the lines paired with the slices to be taken for the result.

The code then goes through the lines and builds a data structure (`keyword2lines`) mapping the keyword to the result lines for that keyword.

At the end the collected lines for each keyword are written to the result file.

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print(
            '2 Parameters expected: You must introduce your pdb file'
            ' and a name for output file.'
        )
        sys.exit(1)
    input_filename, output_filename = sys.argv[1:3]
    # 
    # Pairs of keywords and slices that should be taken from the line
    # starting with the respective keyword.
    # 
    keyword_and_slices = [
        ('HELIX', [slice(3, 6, 2), slice(6, 9, 2)]),
        (
            'SHEET',
            [slice(a, b, 2) for a, b in [(4, 7), (7, 10), (12, 15), (16, 19)]]
        ),
        ('DBREF', [slice(3, 5), slice(8, 10)]),
    ]
    keyword2lines = defaultdict(list)
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            for keyword, slices in keyword_and_slices:
                if line.startswith(keyword):
                    parts = line.split()
                    result_line = [keyword]
                    for index in slices:
                        result_line.extend(parts[index])
                    keyword2lines[keyword].append(' '.join(result_line) + '\n')

    with open(output_filename, 'w') as out_file:
        for keyword in ['DBREF', 'HELIX', 'SHEET']:
            out_file.writelines(keyword2lines[keyword])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code follows your text in checking if a line *starts* with a keyword, instead your code which checks if a keyword is *anywhere* within a line.

It also makes sure all files are closed properly by using the `with` statement.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the tuple created on RHS in your assignments to string.

```
 # Replace this with statement given below
 cols_id = dbref[0], dbref[3:5], dbref[8:10]

 # Create a string out of the tuple
 cols_id = ''.join((dbref[0], dbref[3:5], dbref[8:10]))
```

Comment: It doesn't work... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funcional2.py", line 18, in <module>
    cols_id = ''.join((dbref[0], dbref[3:5], dbref[8:10]))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found